# Who is Isvara? Is it just another name of Saguna Brahman? Or he is different from both Saguna and Nirguna Brahman?

Tags: vedanta, advaita

I understand the difference between Nirguna and Saguna Brahman. But I am confused about Isvara. Who is Isvara? Is it just another name of Saguna Brahman? Or he is different from both Saguna and Nirguna Brahman? Here I am only looking for answers from the Advaitic perspective.

Comment: Isvara is the same as Saguna Brahman.

Comment: Everyone is Nirguna Brahman by default. Ishwara/Shakti are the collection of self-realized yogi Atmans called Saguna Brahma while earthly humans and animals are also Atmans but imperfect due to body's ego and temporary sense desires and have to reincarnate until realize perfect Self "Ayam Ātmā Brahma (अयम् आत्मा ब्रह्म) - "This Self (Atman) is Brahman"--Mandukya Upanishad 1.2